# Regex to remove last single special character

Tags: regex

I want to remove last single special character if it exists in the string.

I/P : Hello my name is XYZ -
O/P : Hello my name is XYZ

I/P : What time is it /
O/P : What time is it

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

If with "special character" you mean non-alphanumeric and non-white space, try replacing

```
^(.*)[\W\S]$
```

with

```
$1
```

Comment: You mean something like : str= str.replace("^(.*)[\\W\\S]$", "$1");

Comment: Yes, you have not explained the language, so I don't know the exact synthax.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work! BTW I am using Java

Comment: If so try with `[^\w\s]` rather than `[\W\S]`. If it still does not work, remove `^` and `$`.

Comment: @coderahul94 [Here](http://www.fiddle.re/a9c9fa) it worked (click on "Go").